# jQuery toggle show/hide with image plus text

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I have found this jquery toggle code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z7F75/1/). Now I would like to add a text "Click to Open" that is vertically aligned to the middle of the image.

This is the code:

CSS:

```
.toggle{
    display:inline-block;
    height:48px;
    width:48px;
    background:url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/pixelmixer/basic/48/plus-icon.png");
}
.toggle.expanded{
    background:url("http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/onebit/PNG/onebit_32.png");
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $content = $(".content").hide();
    $(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
        $content.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="toggle"></div>
<div class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</div>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/WN4A2/

Comment: I would like the text next to the image (to the right)

Comment: I appreciate your help. This is another example of how I would like it to be (http://demo.webstutorial.com/slideToggle/), but instead of the symbol + or -, I would like to use an image. (I guess it was confusing when I said vertically aligned). Can you help me? I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

Add `:after` pseudo elements to toggle, and some line height.

```
.toggle:after{
    content:"Click to Open";
    display:block;
    height:48px;
    line-height:48px;
    width:88px;
    margin-left:48px;
}
.toggle.expanded:after{
     content:"Click to Close";
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mrQN6/)**

Or try this way:

Html:

```
<div class="toggle">
  <span class="image"></span>
  <span class="text">Some Random text here. Hello</span>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.toggle {
    height:48px;
    line-height:48px;
}
.toggle .image {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    height:48px;
    width:48px;
    background:url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/pixelmixer/basic/48/plus-icon.png");
}
.toggle .text {
    margin-left : 10px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yx5wN/)**

Comment: The problem is that the text will vary. Could you please take a look at this: http://demo.webstutorial.com/slideToggle/ and instead of the symbols (+/-), use an image? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make the div.toggle an img instead of a div. Set the src attribute to the background-image that's specified in the CSS. Give the img the following CSS

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

Give the div.content a display of inline. Use the following JS

```
var $content = $(".content").hide();
 $(".toggle").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).attr("src", "http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/onebit/PNG/onebit_32.png");
    $content.slideToggle();
 });
```

The problem is that the text that you want to vertically align is much too long and once it creates a line break, whatever text is below the line break won't be aligned along the center of the img.

See the [new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lnlance09/z7F75/272/)

Comment: Hi Lance, basically what I want is something like this: (http://demo.webstutorial.com/slideToggle/) but instead of the symbol + or less, I'll use an image. Any idea? Thank you.